Can't spyOn second & third call jest
I can't do spyOn on the second and third calls of a function in a test with jest
I tried to do it like this by following the documentation :
it("should succeed after retry on first attempt failure", async () => {
  jest.spyOn(nukiService, "lockDoors")
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 503 }))
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 200 }));

  expect((await nukiService.lockDoorsWithRetry()).status)
    .toBe(200);
});
    
it("should fail after 3 retries", async () => {
  jest.spyOn(nukiService, "lockDoors")
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 503 }))
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 503 }))
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 503 }));
    
  expect((await nukiService.lockDoorsWithRetry()).status)
    .toBe(424);
});

My test fails because of timout so I think the problem comes from the spyOn which does not work :
● NukiService › handle doors › should succeed after retry on first attempt failure

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      85 |     });
      86 |
    > 87 |     it("should succeed after retry on first attempt failure", async () => {
         |     ^
      88 |       jest.spyOn(nukiService, "lockDoors")
      89 |         .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 503 }))
      90 |         .mockResolvedValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ status: 200 }));

      at services/nuki.service.spec.ts:87:5
      at services/nuki.service.spec.ts:18:3
      at Object.<anonymous> (services/nuki.service.spec.ts:5:1)


Please provide the code under test. Show the code of nukiService

The timeout is being thrown from the test. It indicates that nukiService.lockDoorsWithRetry() is taking longer than the value set for the test timeout.
Try debugging inside of nukiService.lockDoorsWithRetry() to see what the behaviour of the internal code is and whether it is what you were expecting.
